# Tomcat no idea error?

Tags: java, tomcat

well I have no idea what this error is about, anyone familier with this? -

```
    Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performanc
e in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOW
S;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;.
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting propert
y 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GenTreeUploader' did not find a matchi
ng property.
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1099 ms
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig init
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context []
java.io.IOException: The device is not ready
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:414)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:589)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.ja
va:703)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:843
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:387)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.m
etadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp7\wtpwebapps\ROOT does not exist
 or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.
java:138)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardConte
xt.java:5002)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5182)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig init
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/GenTreeUploader]
java.io.IOException: The device is not ready
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:414)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:589)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.ja
va:703)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:843
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:387)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.m
etadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp7\wtpwebapps\GenTreeUploader doe
s not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.
java:138)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardConte
xt.java:5002)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5182)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/GenTreeUploader] startup failed due to previous errors
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Ca
talina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/GenTreeUploader]] so no cleanup
 was performed for that container
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context
. Unable to find [comp].
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.ja
va:988)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResourc
es.java:970)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext
.java:5590)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Bir 18, 2013 5:03:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat7_x86\webapps\docs
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat7_x86\webapps\examples
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCa
che', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1c7a25d')
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat7_x86\webapps\host-manager
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat7_x86\webapps\manager
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Bir 18, 2013 5:03:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1090 ms
```

Comment: Try the instructions listed at http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/#Install and tests

Comment: try to delete tomcat temp files under {TOMCAT_HOME}/temp

Answer (score 0):

```
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context []
    java.io.IOException: The device is not ready
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
```

Looks like you have used a document base that is a remote file system, or else you have some cataastrophic disk errors.

Comment: More likely just a missing file and a bad exception message: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp7\wtpwebapps\ROOT does not exist
 or is not a readable directory`

Comment: @JimGarrison You're putting the cart before the horse. Your exception is a result of the original exception, not its cause.